How to group legend labels in customized order with python plotly iplot?
I'm using plotly iplot for a butterfly plot, with a couple of dozen traces, I would like to group the legend labels in customized order, wonder anyone know how to do it. I did find examples of customizing legends using plotly express, but my current plotting is with iplot.
Searched online before without finding direct resource, hope to find methods to group the labels in customized order

Hi and welcome on SO. Do you mind to have a look at [ask] and produce a [mcve]?
